# SQLite Database search in Xamarin Forms

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a search bar with list. The list will display all the suggestions from the database. The problem my search query is not working. I am getting zero count. I am not sure  if my query has a correct syntax.

```
private void NameSearch_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var keyword = NameSearch.Text;

        var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
        var conn = db.GetConnection();

        var getCaf = conn.QueryAsync<ContactsTable>("SELECT FileAS FROM tblContacts WHERE FileAs LIKE '%?%'", keyword);
        var resultCount = getCaf.Result.Count;

        if (resultCount > 0)
        {
            var result = getCaf.Result;
            lstName.ItemsSource = result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you this working in .net standard or pcl ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Query, it contains "`FileAS`" and "`FileAs`" case sensitivity issue. Make sure they both are same and exactly like the column name.

Change your Query to:

```
conn.QueryAsync<ContactsTable>($"SELECT FileAS FROM  tblContacts WHERE FileAS LIKE '%{ keyword }%'").ToList();
```

OR

To reduce spelling mistakes you can try following Lambda Expression as Query:

```
conn.Table<ContactsTable>().Where(x => x.FileAS.Contains(keyword)).ToList();
```

So, Your Final Code should look like:

```
private void NameSearch_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var keyword = NameSearch.Text;

    var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
    var conn = db.GetConnection();

    var getCaf = conn.Table<ContactsTable>().Where(x => x.FileAS.Contains(keyword)).ToList();
    var resultCount = getCaf.Count();

    if (resultCount > 0)
    {
        lstName.ItemsSource = getCaf;
    }
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you I saw the FileAS as soon as I posted it haha. You code works thank you